# Cambiar el color del navegador en dispositivos moviles

Tags: javascript, html, css

Quiero cambiar el color del navegador cuando mi página web para cuando esta se encuentre en un dispositivo móvil, ¿Qué propiedad puedo usar? (imagen tomada desde el navegador Chrome).
[image: Ejemplo del resultado que quiero obtener]

Comment: ¿Puedes adjuntar tu código de cómo lo has intentado?

Comment: echa un vistazo a este enlace, aparentemente es lo que necesitas : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26960703/how-to-change-the-color-of-header-bar-and-address-bar-in-newest-chrome-version-o

Answer (score 1):

```
<meta name="theme-color" content="#4285f4"/>
```

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/369422)